# Buddypress: Cleaning up db after deleting group

Tags: wordpress, buddypress, bbpress

For some reasons that I cannot understand, Buddypress seems not to clean up after itself when deleting groups. The desired functionality for me would be that all forums, topics, posts and meta-data belonging to the group being deleted also get removed from their respective tables, but this unfortunately does not occur (I’m using the Group Forums btw…). Is this the desired behaviour, a flaw or a bug?

Not only that I find clogging db:s with unnecessary information bad, it also makes the development of a custom plugin for more advanced thread moving a lot harder for me since I now have to write my own clean ups. Is there a “delete_forum($forum_id)” function or something similar that takes care of this? Or maybe any other function? Or am I completely missing something out here?

Setup:
WordPress Version 3.2.1
BuddyPress Version 1.5.1

Answer (score 1):

Here is my situation and how I resolved it:

Questions:

- Did you transport the site from another server or domain? (Usually from a development sandbox or the like?)
- Files to check: bbpress.config file (Mine had the old development address. I was unaware that a URL was stored in here.)
- After adjustment: install group forums using existing install!
- After that: Delete and re-add groups
- Forums work and old forum topics are gone. I do not have ANY idea of how this functioned without the bbpress config file being close to correct, but it did!!! Until the delete groups command was issued!

Hopefully Buddypress continues to strive for warning messages when something is amiss!

Comment: The problem seems to be that BP keeps the old posts for "reference" and only deactivates them instead of deleting them, but since I have left that project long time ago, I will not attempt to fix it anymore. I chose the hard way to clean up things manually. But to answer you question, I didn't transport the site from any other domain, it was installed "on site".